# htaccess recipe for moving folder doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I have a structure as follows: `www.domain.com/folder`

Included in the html files in the folder are includes that reference: `/folder/textfile.txt`

I need a recipe that will move the folder to: `www.domain.com/sites/folder`
and take care of all the includes in the folder.

I tried a `RewriteRule` as follows

```
RewriteRule /folder /sites/folder
```

That didn't really work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to include the full redirected path, so `RewriteRule ^/folder(/(.*))? /sites/folder/$2`

Comment: oh and do you want to redirect them silently? (no URL change)? If so, you'll need to change `/sites/folder` to a full absolute path for your server (e.g. `/var/www/html/sites/folder`)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.  I'm getting a not found error.  I have the full path but it can't find it.

Comment: In that case you need to post exactly the rule you're using and a rough (but accurate) directory structure.

Comment: Okay, here it is: RewriteRule ^/search(/(.*))? /usr/www/users/htm/sites/newsearch/$2

Comment: In that case, I have to ask the silly things: does that folder exist (it's usually HTML not HTM for example)? (And does it have the content you're requesting?) Have you turned the rewrite engine on (`RewriteEngine on`)? Is this code in the core configuration or a htaccess file? If an access file, is it certainly running and has permission to rewrite? Are there any other rewrite rules which might be conflicting?

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Yes to all those questions.  HTM happens to be my initials so that's why that folder exists.  The recipe is in the .htaccess file and I do have permission to run it. Yes, the RewriteEngine is on.  I do have other recipes and I'll have to look through them to look for a conflict.  I haven't been able to find one yet.  I moved the search folder to /sites/newsearch so the content IS there.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, I created a new .htaccess file and left only the recipe (after turning on the RewriteEngine) and it still didn't work.  I'm stumped. I'm just trying to move the folder out of the root, BUT keep the url as it is now (www.domain.com/search).  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, hang on. So are your visitors going to /search/ or are they going to another page which *includes* pages in /search/? If the former, this should work (maybe a capitalisation error?), even if the files include other files. If the latter, mod_rewrite doesn't apply and you'll have to make a soft link (shortcut) in the file system, or change the paths.

Comment: My visitors have been going to /search/ but I want to move that folder out of the root and have no effect on the visitor.  I don't want to lose the path for SEO reasons.

Comment: Ah! is the htaccess file inside `/search/`? That would make sense. If so, you need to change the line to `RewriteRule ^(.*) /usr/www/users/htm/sites/newsearch/$1`

Comment: Nope, the .htaccess is in the root.  I'm stumped.  It must be another recipe somewhere because I can't get it to work.  Thanks for the help though.